# PHP array_walk require_once

Tags: php, arrays

I was just wondering if anyone knew why I can't use `require_once` as a callback for `array_walk`.  I can just include it in an anonymous function and run that, but it gives an invalid callback error for the usage:

```
$includes = array(
    'file1.php',
    'file2.php',
    'file3.php'
);
array_walk($includes, 'require_once');
```

Comment: require_once isn't a function, it's a language construct, so it can't be called directly as a callback function

Comment: ...it would also error with an invalid callback if you tried to use `array_walk($includes, 'echo')` as `echo` is a language construct not a function.

Comment: +1 to both previous comments. But seriously, any good reason why you aren't just using a `foreach()` loop here?

Comment: Thanks guys, just did a foreach loop like zigi said, but it perturbed me that I couldn't do it on a single line and keep my code extra clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`require_once` is not a PHP function, but a control structure.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to waste more time finding out what's wrong. Just use:

```
$includes = [
    'file1.php',
    'file2.php',
    'file3.php'
];
foreach($includes as $include) {
    require_once($include);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create

```
function my_require_once ($name)
{
    require_once $name;
}
```

The other guys are right, it's not a function. It operates outside the mode of the PHP code you write. The contents of the file are brought into the global namespace, even if it is called within a functiion, as above.

I use this, for example to do stuff like

```
function my_log ($message, $extra_data = null)
{
    global $php_library;
    require_once "$php_library/log.php"; // big and complicated functions, so defer loading

    my_log_fancy_stuff ($message, $extra_data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Martin wrote, require once is not a function, so your solution with array_walk is not been working. If you want to include multiple files, you can try to use this:

```
function require_multi($files) 
{
    $files = func_get_args();
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        require_once($file);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
require_multi("fil1.php", "file2.php", "file3.php");
```